# Usage of Phantom JS in Production Phase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, phantomjs

I use the class `phantomJSdriver` in my asp.net mvc project and it installed an executable file in order to use PhantomJS.

I have used the code `Install-Package PhantomJS` from the package manager console.

I have some questions:

- Will phantom JS with exe file will be working in production phase and in the webhotel?
- When I use phantom JS, it displayed a firewall and I wonder if it gonna be the same result in production phase in the web hotel?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will phantom JS with exe file will be working in production phase and in the webhotel?

Yes. The PhantomJS.exe file will be deployed together with your application as it will be part of it.

> When I use phantom JS, it displayed a firewall and I wonder if it gonna be the same result in production phase in the web hotel?

Yes also. The executable PhantomJS.exe has to be authorized to access the Internet through the different firewalls you have in place on your production environment.

Comment: "Yes also. The executable PhantomJS.exe has to be authorized to access the Internet through the different firewalls you have in place on your production environment."  I understand, in this context you have to communicate with staff of the webhotel in order to make the phantomjs exe to pass the firewall.

Comment: Exactly yes.
Do not hesitate to accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Thank you for your help!